Inserto datos en una tabla en SQL Server pero todos aparecen como null
actualmente estamos intentando almacenar datos en una tabla de Sql Server, los cuales proceden de un JSON. En el proceso hacemos la deserilizacion y todo va bien hasta ese punto, luego hacemos una tranformacion de datos para que la insersion sea mas sencilla, pero en este punto es donde tenemos las dificultades actuales.
Con el animo de dar el mayor lujo de detalles, comenzamos a exponer la novedad.
Este es un objeto del JSON que deserializamos:
{
  "uniqueID": 1134354075,
  "plate": "VD-470",
  "GPSDate": "2024-12-01T06:08:30.000Z",
  "latitude": 7.02644,
  "longitude": -74.71615,
  "speed": 0,
  "course": 0,
  "odometer": 22960.149,
  "receivedDate": "2024-12-01T06:08:31.000Z",
  "stateInfo": {
    "stateData": {
      "stateParam": "11+",
      "stateDetail": "Parado"
    }
  },
  "GPSQuality": 1,
  "CANInfo": {
    "CANData": [
      {
        "CANParam": "totalFuel",
        "CANValue": "55556"
      },
      {
        "CANParam": "fuelLevel1",
        "CANValue": "89.2"
      },
      {
        "CANParam": "RPM",
        "CANValue": "0"
      },
      {
        "CANParam": "axisWeight",
        "CANValue": "49600"
      },
      {
        "CANParam": "speed",
        "CANValue": "0"
      },
      {
        "CANParam": "coolantTemperature",
        "CANValue": "83"
      },
      {
        "CANParam": "ambientAirTemperature",
        "CANValue": "30"
      }
    ]
  },
  "peripheralsInfo": {
    "peripheralsData": [
      {
        "peripheralsParam": "Motor",
        "peripheralsValue": "Parado"
      },
      {
        "peripheralsParam": "Bateria",
        "peripheralsValue": "Cargando"
      },
      {
        "peripheralsParam": "Pedal panico",
        "peripheralsValue": "off"
      },
      {
        "peripheralsParam": "Inmovilizador",
        "peripheralsValue": "Bloqueado"
      }
    ]
  },
  "geofenceInfo": {
    "geofenceData": {
      "geofencePoint": "PUNTO 159",
      "geofencePolygon": "MAG2_ZonaOperativa"
    }
  }
}

Como se puede notar claramente, tenemos datos en:
"stateParam": "11+",
"stateDetail": "Parado"
"CANParam": "totalFuel",
"CANValue": "55556"
"CANParam": "fuelLevel1",
"CANValue": "89.2"
Estos son algunos de los ejemplos que desamos presentar para evidenciar la noveadad que estamos teniendo, pues a pesar de tener datos, al insertarlos en nuestra tabla, insertan como null.
Continuando con el proceso, presentamos las clases principales que utilizamos para hacer la deserializacion del JSON:
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DAL
{
    public class vehicleInfo
    {
        public long uniqueID { get; set; }
        public string? plate { get; set; }
        public DateTime GPSDate { get; set; }
        public float latitude { get; set; }
        public float longitude { get; set; }
        public int speed { get; set; }
        public int course { get; set; }
        public float odometer { get; set; }
        public DateTime receivedDate { get; set; }
        public stateInfo? stateInfoParametro { get; set; }
        public int GPSQuality { get; set; }
        public CANInfo? CANInfoParametro { get; set; }
        public peripheralsInfo? peripheralsInfoParametro { get; set; }
        public geofenceInfo? geofenceInfoParametro { get; set; }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DAL
{
    public class stateInfo
    {
        public stateData? stateDataParametro { get; set; }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DAL
{
    public class stateData
    {
        public string? stateParam { get; set; }
        public string? stateDetail { get; set; }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DAL
{
    public class CANInfo
    {
        public CANData[]? CANDataParametro { get; set; } 
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DAL
{
    public class CANData
    {
        public string? CANParam { get; set; }
        public string? CANValue { get; set; }
    }
}

Las siguiente clase, la utilizamos para transformar los datos que ya deserlizamos del JSON y volviendolos del tipo que la tabla a insertar los datos tiene:
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace DAL
{
    public class GpsAPIRESTFlotasnet
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long Registro { get; set; }   
        public long uniqueID { get; set; }
        public string? plate { get; set; }
        public DateTime GPSDate { get; set; }
        public int speed { get; set; }
        [Precision(53)]
        [Column(TypeName = "float(53)")]
        public float odometer { get; set; }
        public DateTime receivedDate { get; set; }
        public string? stateParamExcesoVelocidadGeocerca { get; set; }
        public string? stateParamAlarmaLimiteVelocidad { get; set; }
        public string? stateParamAlarmaACLAceleracionBrusca { get; set; }
        public string? stateParamAlarmaACLFrenadaBrusca { get; set; }
        public string? CANValueTotalFuel { get; set; }
        public string? CANValueFuelLevel1 { get; set; }
        public string? CANValueRPM { get; set; }
        public string? CANValueOdometer { get; set; }
        public string? CANValuesSpeed { get; set; }
        public string? CANValueCoolantTemperature { get; set; }
        public string? CANValueAmbientAirTemperature { get; set; }  
        public string? CANValueEngineHours { get; set; }
        public string? peripheralsValueMotor { get; set; }
        public string? geofencePolygon { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaInsert { get; set; }
    }
}

Esta es el metodo con el cual hemos tenido dificultades, el cual es un metodo de tranformacion de datos:
/// <summary>
        /// 2024-11-15 11:00: Transformar los datos del JSON deserializados a los del tipo utilizado en la tabla. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="info"></param>
        /// <returns>Datos tabla</returns>
        public GpsAPIRESTFlotasnet ToGpsAPIRESTFlotasnet(vehicleInfo info) => new GpsAPIRESTFlotasnet
        {
            uniqueID = info.uniqueID,
            plate = info.plate,
            // 2024-12-19 17:08: Debido a que los datos entregados a la tabla tienen una diferencia de +5 horas,
            // fue necesario restarle las 5 horas a los dato recibidos.
            GPSDate = info.GPSDate.AddHours(-5),
            speed = info.speed,
            odometer = info.odometer,
            // 2024-12-19 17:08: Debido a que los datos entregados a la tabla tienen una diferencia de +5 horas,
            // fue necesario restarle las 5 horas a los dato recibidos.
            receivedDate = info.receivedDate.AddHours(-5),
            stateParamExcesoVelocidadGeocerca = info.stateInfoParametro?.stateDataParametro?.stateParam == "11+" ? info.stateInfoParametro?.stateDataParametro?.stateDetail : null, 
            stateParamAlarmaLimiteVelocidad = info.stateInfoParametro?.stateDataParametro?.stateParam == "35+" ? info.stateInfoParametro?.stateDataParametro?.stateDetail : null,
            stateParamAlarmaACLAceleracionBrusca = info.stateInfoParametro?.stateDataParametro?.stateParam == "214" ? info.stateInfoParametro?.stateDataParametro?.stateDetail : null,
            stateParamAlarmaACLFrenadaBrusca = info.stateInfoParametro?.stateDataParametro?.stateParam == "213" ? info.stateInfoParametro?.stateDataParametro?.stateDetail : null,
            CANValueTotalFuel = info.CANInfoParametro?.CANDataParametro?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "totalFuel")?.CANValue,
            CANValueFuelLevel1 = info.CANInfoParametro?.CANDataParametro?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "fuelLevel1")?.CANValue,
            CANValueRPM = info.CANInfoParametro?.CANDataParametro?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "RPM")?.CANValue,
            CANValueOdometer = info.CANInfoParametro?.CANDataParametro?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "odometer")?.CANValue,
            CANValuesSpeed = info.CANInfoParametro?.CANDataParametro?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "speed")?.CANValue,
            CANValueCoolantTemperature = info.CANInfoParametro?.CANDataParametro?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "coolantTemperature")?.CANValue,
            CANValueAmbientAirTemperature = info.CANInfoParametro?.CANDataParametro?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "ambientAirTemperature")?.CANValue,
            CANValueEngineHours = info.CANInfoParametro?.CANDataParametro?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "engineHours")?.CANValue,
            peripheralsValueMotor = info.peripheralsInfoParametro?.peripheralsDataParametro?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.peripheralsParam == "Motor")?.peripheralsValue,
            geofencePolygon = info.geofenceInfoParametro?.geofenceDataParametro?.geofencePoint,
            FechaInsert = DateTime.Now
        };

Luego procedemos a utlizar los metodos que nos permiten insertar los datos en la tabla SQL server, los cuales son:
/// <summary>
        /// 2024-11-15 11:00: Insertar los datos del JSON deserializado en la tabla.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>No retorna</returns>
        public async Task InsertarDatosOperacionAsync()
        {
            var deserialized = await GetVehicleInfoByDateAsync();
            var gpsDatas = deserialized.Select(ToGpsAPIRESTFlotasnet);
            _context.GpsAPIRESTFlotasnet.AddRange(gpsDatas);
            // 2024-12-18 15:49: Se utiliza el método asíncrono (SaveChangesAsync) para esperar a que la operación de guardado
            // se complete antes de continuar.
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            // 2024-12-18 15:50: Envolvemos el segundo método en un Task.Run para ejecutarlo en un nuevo hilo. Esto permite que
            // la ejecución continúe sin bloquear el hilo actual. La tarea continuada se ejecuta automáticamente después de que
            // la primera tarea se complete con éxito.
            await Task.Run(() => InsertarDatosFechasControl());
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// 2024-12-18 15:00: Insertar datos de las fechas consultadas en su respectiva tabla.
        /// </summary>
        public void InsertarDatosFechasControl()
        {
            var t = RegisroIncial();
            _context.GpsAPIRESTFlotasnetControl.AddRange(t);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

Los metodos funcionan correctamente e insertar datos en las tablas, pero la gran novedad, es que los siguientes campos, estan recibiendo todo los datos como null:
stateParamExcesoVelocidadGeocerca = info.stateInfoParametro?.stateDataParametro?.stateParam == "11+" ? info.stateInfoParametro?.stateDataParametro?.stateDetail : null, 
            stateParamAlarmaLimiteVelocidad = info.stateInfoParametro?.stateDataParametro?.stateParam == "35+" ? info.stateInfoParametro?.stateDataParametro?.stateDetail : null,
            stateParamAlarmaACLAceleracionBrusca = info.stateInfoParametro?.stateDataParametro?.stateParam == "214" ? info.stateInfoParametro?.stateDataParametro?.stateDetail : null,
            stateParamAlarmaACLFrenadaBrusca = info.stateInfoParametro?.stateDataParametro?.stateParam == "213" ? info.stateInfoParametro?.stateDataParametro?.stateDetail : null,
            CANValueTotalFuel = info.CANInfoParametro?.CANDataParametro?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "totalFuel")?.CANValue,
            CANValueFuelLevel1 = info.CANInfoParametro?.CANDataParametro?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "fuelLevel1")?.CANValue,
            CANValueRPM = info.CANInfoParametro?.CANDataParametro?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "RPM")?.CANValue,
            CANValueOdometer = info.CANInfoParametro?.CANDataParametro?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "odometer")?.CANValue,
            CANValuesSpeed = info.CANInfoParametro?.CANDataParametro?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "speed")?.CANValue,
            CANValueCoolantTemperature = info.CANInfoParametro?.CANDataParametro?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "coolantTemperature")?.CANValue,
            CANValueAmbientAirTemperature = info.CANInfoParametro?.CANDataParametro?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "ambientAirTemperature")?.CANValue,
            CANValueEngineHours = info.CANInfoParametro?.CANDataParametro?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "engineHours")?.CANValue,

Claramente en la estructura JSON que presentamos al principio, existen datos.
Agradecemos nos ayuden a identificar en que punto estamos fallando para acceder a los datos que deseamos registrar en cada campo y de igual forma agradecemos sus recomendaciones y observaciones.

Más allá del problema que trienes con los NULL, no deberías sumar o restar horas a una fecha. EN lugar de DateTime deberíás usar DateTimeOffset para almacenar también ese offset de -05 en la BD y olvidarte de las conversiones de fecha,. Solamnete al mostrar la fecha asegurate de utilizar la zona horaria correcta

await Task.Run(() => InsertarDatosFechasControl()); no es un error, pero es un ALTO AHI.. el metodo InsertadDatos.... deberia ser asincrono, y las llamadas y estoy seguro que EF tiene un metodo para guardar el contexto asincrono tambien. De esa forma, no tenes que hacer un taskrun (que ni siquiera estas controlando que le pasa a la vuelta)...

@CarlosMuñoz, gracias por su observacion y recomendacion

@gbianchi, esto lo utilizamos para insertar un solo registro al ejecutarse el metodo. A pesar de ser un solo registro, consideras que es necesario que sea asincrono?. Agradecemos sus observaciones.

@CarlosMuñoz, en esta parte es donde resto las horas: GPSDate = info.GPSDate.AddHours(-5), receivedDate = info.receivedDate.AddHours(-5). Nos podrias indicar con un ejemplo la forma correcta o recomendable de hacerlo.

@GermanDavid la cantidad de registros no tiene nada que ver... si en guardar ese registro tarda 10 segundos, es lo mismo... y ya es asincronico pero de una manera ultra complicada. Todas tus interacciones a la db, el SO, o una api deben ser asincronicas... todo lo que pueda llegar a tardar, debe serlo...

gracias @gbianchi, procedemos a realizar lo recomendado.

De lo que observo el detalle es el siguiente; tu objeto JSON tiene stateInfo y no stateInfoParametro; esto en los elemento raíz del objeto es (para simplificar):
{
  "uniqueID": 1134354075,
  "plate": "VD-470",
  "GPSDate": "2024-12-01T06:08:30.000Z",
  "latitude": 7.02644,
  "longitude": -74.71615,
  "speed": 0,
  "course": 0,
  "odometer": 22960.149,
  "receivedDate": "2024-12-01T06:08:31.000Z",
  "stateInfo": {
    "stateData": {
      "stateParam": "11+",
      "stateDetail": "Parado"
    }
  },
  "GPSQuality": 1,
  "CANInfo": {
    "CANData": [/* varios objectos */]
  },
  "peripheralsInfo": {
    "peripheralsData": [/* varios objectos */]
  },
  "geofenceInfo": {
    "geofenceData": {
      "geofencePoint": "PUNTO 159",
      "geofencePolygon": "MAG2_ZonaOperativa"
    }
  }
}

Mientras que tu clase destino es:
public class vehicleInfo
{
    public long uniqueID { get; set; }
    public string? plate { get; set; }
    public DateTime GPSDate { get; set; }
    public float latitude { get; set; }
    public float longitude { get; set; }
    public int speed { get; set; }
    public int course { get; set; }
    public float odometer { get; set; }
    public DateTime receivedDate { get; set; }
    public stateInfo? stateInfoParametro { get; set; }
    public int GPSQuality { get; set; }
    public CANInfo? CANInfoParametro { get; set; }
    public peripheralsInfo? peripheralsInfoParametro { get; set; }
    public geofenceInfo? geofenceInfoParametro { get; set; }
}

Lo que debe coincidir es el nombre de la propiedad (sensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas) en el objeto destino; no el nombre del tipo de dato (en tu caso clase como lo actualmente lo tienes).
Es decir, haciendo los cambios que correspondan y a tú código impacte menos; haciendo en la clase sería:
public class vehicleInfo
{
    public long uniqueID { get; set; }
    public string? plate { get; set; }
    public DateTime GPSDate { get; set; }
    public float latitude { get; set; }
    public float longitude { get; set; }
    public int speed { get; set; }
    public int course { get; set; }
    public float odometer { get; set; }
    public DateTime receivedDate { get; set; }
    public stateInfo? stateInfo { get; set; }
    public int GPSQuality { get; set; }
    public CANInfo? CANInfo { get; set; }
    public peripheralsInfo? peripheralsInfo { get; set; }
    public geofenceInfo? geofenceInfo { get; set; }
}

Algunos cambios stateInfoParametro quedó como stateInfo... y así otros.

Aquí estoy ilustrando el cambio del nombre en la propiedad (pudiera haberseme pasado alguna mayúscula/minúscula y/o dejar/quitar alguna letra demás) dejo a tu consideración el cambio del tipo de datos/clase (como deba ser) que corresponde a la propiedad respectiva.


Gracias @RobertoLeOr, no teniamos claro que los nombres de los parametros debian coincidir con el JSON y en su lugar, pensabamos que tenian que coincidir con los nombres de las clases. Gracias por la ayuda.
